# Default path in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, csv-import, vba

The goal is to automate a daily task to open a workbook, import .csv files and perform some formatting, save, and exit excel, the only requirement being the computer is on.  I'm using the windows task scheduler to open a macro enabled workbook on a daily basis.  With help from this site, I added the argument /p "my specific path" to the task to set the import path I wish to access.  Then, using the Workbook_open function, the import is performed, however, the following error occurs while highlighting the .refresh backgroundquery:=false line:

```
Run-time error '1004':
Excel cannot find the text file to refresh this external data range.
Check to make sure the text file has not been moved or renamed, then try
  the refresh again.
```

Now, if I select "End" to stop the debugger and simply run the macro on my own, everything works fine.  The path is on a network, if that matters.  I can post parts of the code if that would help, but it's pretty long.
It goes without saying I'm no VBA whiz, so I've pieced the code together,but everything works except the initial import of the .csv file.
Thanks in advance for any advice.

Relevant code:

```
R = 1
FName = Dir(Path & DayTime & ".csv")

Do While FName <> ""
    ImportCsvFile FName, ActiveSheet.Cells(R, 1)
    R = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count + 1
    DayTime = DayTime + 1
    FName = Dir(Path & DayTime & ".csv")
Loop

Sub ImportCsvFile(FileName As Variant, Position As Range)
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
  "TEXT;" & FileName _
  , Destination:=Position)
  .Name = Replace(FileName, ".csv", "")
  .FieldNames = True
  .RowNumbers = False
  .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
  .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
  .BackgroundQuery = True
  .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
  .SavePassword = False
  .SaveData = True
  .AdjustColumnWidth = True
  .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
  .TextFilePlatform = xlMacintosh
  .TextFileStartRow = 1
  .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
  .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
  .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
  .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
  .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
  .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
  .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
  .TextFileOtherDelimiter = ","
  .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
  .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Show us the code that is not working.

Comment: You can use `ChDir "Drive:\Path\to\folder"` to set the default path.  It's hard to say if this will correct your issue without seeing the code though.

Comment: Shot in the dark... Remove `backgroundquery:=false` from your code.

Comment: What value does Path have before this? If you are not sure add a line: `debug.print "Path: " & Path`, then press Ctrl+G to open the immediate window and see what is printed out when you run this.

Comment: First few lines, excluding variable declarations:

    Dim Path As String
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    Path = "\\drive\dept\... etc ...\flowlog\"

Comment: @user2795886 and have you checked that it is set correctly before the `Do while` loop kicks in?

Comment: From the "Immediate" window, after manually running the task with your print code inserted just prior to the do while loop:
Path: \\drive\dept\... etc ...\flowlog\
Apologies for the delay, at lunch.

Comment: I'd like to stress the fact that the error occurs when opening the file (via task scheduler or shortcut), but runs just as I expect it to after exiting the debugger and re-running the macro.  Is there something wrong with my open_workbook code?

    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call ImportAllCSV
    Application.Quit
    End Sub

This is located in the Object "ThisWorkbook"

Comment: Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: "Excel cannot find the text file" When it gives the error it stops in debug mode. Before exiting debug mode check the variables. What is the path? It should be a full path that actually has the file in question.

Comment: You need to explore what is different when first started versus running the macro again. "I added the argument /p "my specific path"" Try setting the path in the code and see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FName = Dir(Path & DayTime & ".csv")` returns only the filename or blank if the file does not exist.

Add the path to the parameter and it should work fine. I also prefer using Call and ().

```
Call ImportCsvFile(Path & FName, ActiveSheet.Cells(R, 1))
```

Apparently the current directory changed after you started using the debugger. It must have changed from the folder that didn't have your files to the folder that does. That's why it worked when running it the second time. I'm not what caused that.

Also if you would've checked the `FileName` variable within the `ImportCsvFile` sub when the error occurred you would have seen that the path was missing.